# How to get time stamp from History?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I'm working with Openfire & XMPP. I successfully implement group chatting in it.

Now when i fetch history, it return me time stmap, now how do i fetch that stamp form responce. Here is my response:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat" from="ios@conference.test/bhavin" to="bhavin@test/8o4ojvfnkm">
<body>sad</body>
<delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" stamp="2016-08-02T07:00:23.678Z" from="ios@conference.test"/>
</message>
```

i can get `from` and message `body` from it using :

```
[message attributeForName:@"from"];
[message attributeForName:@"body"];
```

but How do i fetch stamp form it ?

Comment: try [message attributeForName:@"stamp"];

Comment: i tried ... it return nil

Comment: can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

try below code hope this may helpful,

`NSXMLElement *value = [message attributeForName:@"stamp"];
                NSString  *streamValueString = [value stringValue];`

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this. Just try this :

```
[[[message elementForName:@"delay" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:delay"] attributeForName:@"stamp"] stringValue]
```